# update money base value in plugin crm2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I have a question relating to crm money field(estimatedrevenue) this is custom field and decimal field(RevenueIncludingTax). I calculate the currency base value = Math.ceil(RevenueIncludingTax). when I try in Javascript, sometime correct and sometimes wrong.
So I try to write plugin, and update the base value. Although the plugin is working and update value in coding, but when open form it show error message and not update the base value. **I suspect that Can i update the money base value?**

Here is my plug-in code,

```
public class EstimatedRevenue : IPlugin
{
    #region Class Level Variables
    //IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    //IOrganizationServiceFactory _serviceFactory = null;
    //IOrganizationService _service = null;
    //IPluginExecutionContext _context = null;

    Entity _target = null;
    Entity _preImage = null;
    Entity _postImage = null;
    Guid _currentUser;
    decimal revinvtax;
    #endregion

    #region  IPlugin Members
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        try
        {
            string message = null;
            IPluginExecutionContext _context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            #region Organization Services
            // Obtain the organization service reference.
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(_context.UserId);
            #endregion

            var ServiceContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);

            _currentUser = _context.UserId;
            message = _context.MessageName.ToLower();

            if (message == "create") 
            {
                if (_context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && _context.InputParameters["Target"] != null)
                    _target = (Entity)_context.InputParameters["Target"];

                if (_context.PreEntityImages.Contains("PreImage") && _context.PreEntityImages["PreImage"] != null)
                    _preImage = (Entity)_context.PreEntityImages["PreImage"];

                if (_context.PostEntityImages.Contains("PostImage") && _context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"] != null)
                    _postImage = (Entity)_context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];

                if (_target.Attributes.Contains("hm_revenueincludingtax"))
                {
                    revinvtax = (decimal)_target.Attributes["hm_revenueincludingtax"];
                    decimal ceilvalue = Math.Ceiling(revinvtax);
                    _target.Attributes["hm_estimatedrevenue_base"] = ceilvalue;
                    service.Update(_target);
                }
            }
            if (message == "update")
            {
                if (_context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && _context.InputParameters["Target"] != null)
                    _target = (Entity)_context.InputParameters["Target"];

                if (_context.PreEntityImages.Contains("PreImage") && _context.PreEntityImages["PreImage"] != null)
                    _preImage = (Entity)_context.PreEntityImages["PreImage"];

                if (_context.PostEntityImages.Contains("PostImage") && _context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"] != null)
                    _postImage = (Entity)_context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];

                if (_target.Attributes.Contains("hm_revenueincludingtax"))
                {
                    revinvtax = (decimal)_target.Attributes["hm_revenueincludingtax"];
                    decimal ceilvalue = Math.Ceiling(revinvtax);
                    _target.Attributes["hm_estimatedrevenue_base"] = ceilvalue;
                    //service.Update(_target);
                    //ServiceContext.AddObject(_target);
                    //ServiceContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

here is the error page when i open form,
[image]

Comment: FYI, clicking the Download Log File will usually give you more information as to what the actual error is...

Answer (score 2):

Don't update the `_base` attribute - its internal. Instead update the attribute you created (`hm_estimatedrevenue`). it'll adopt the currency of the calling user and `_base` will be just taken care of automatically.

Comment: Based on my requirement, I need to update different values for hm_estimatedrevenue value and hm_estimatedrevenue_base value.

Comment: They are intrinsically linked. `hm_estimatedrevenue_base` will be set based on currency conversion from `hm_estimatedrevenue`. You can't update `_base` independently.

Answer (score 0):

`_base` as the name mentioned it is stored in Base Currency value. So if you are in Europe and setup the base currency during installation as Euro, that is value it saves in the `_base`. If you enter 250 euro, `_base` will have a value of 250.

`hm_estimatedrevenue` field is calculated: `_bases/exchange_rate` to accommodate a Multi-currency org.

You however have to update `hm_estimatedrevenue`, since `_base` is a `readonly` field.

Hope this helps.